# AngularJS $filter('date') adds time to result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this setup in `AngularJS`

```
var input = '2015-08-04T06:00:00';
var format = 'yyyy MMM dd - HH:mm:ss';
return $filter('date')(new Date(input), format);
```

However the result is `2015 Aug 04 - 08:00:00` rather than `2015 Aug 04 - 06:00:00` how can this be?

Comment: @Chris Story is right you should try using some Javascript DateTime library like Moment. http://momentjs.com/

Comment: +1 for momentjs. There is even an [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) which provides directives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is not with AngularJS, it is with the JavaScript usage of new Date().  From the JavaScript documentation on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp):

> When setting a date, without specifying the time zone, JavaScript
>   will use the browser's time zone.  In other words: If a date/time is
>   created in GMT (Greenwich Mean Time), the date/time will be converted
>   to CDT (Central US Daylight Time) if a user browses from central US.

What is happening to you is that your time is being translated to your browser's time zone and assuming you were setting the time as GMT.

To prove my point, go to this tester page on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_new_string) and enter the time from your example and you will see the displayed result is actually different.